# How do I center properly in AbsoluteLayout?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I have element a and element b and I want b to overlap a. While I accomplished this with an AbsoluteLayout, it seems like element b isnt properly centered anymore.

Here is a screenshot of how it looks:
[image]

The orange image above is centered out of the AbsoluteLayout as a reference, the label in the background is element a and the red box is element b.

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackLayout  HeightRequest="150"  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <Image x:Name="logo" Aspect="AspectFit"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  Source="percentageLOGOsmall2.png"></Image>
        </StackLayout>
        <AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="Center">

            <Label x:Name="l_trinkeinladung" Text="Lorem ipsum test text" WidthRequest="300" FontSize="Title"
             AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0.5,-1,-1"
             AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
             HorizontalOptions="Center"
             TextColor="White"
             HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                   />
             <ListView HorizontalOptions="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding players}" HeightRequest="270" WidthRequest="200" x:Name="listview1" RowHeight="50" BackgroundColor="Red">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell >
                       /*Stack for properites*/
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </StackLayout>
```

Why is the red listview not centered?

Comment: your `ListView` needs `HorizontalOptions="Center"`

Comment: @Jason didnt fix the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code, you add ListView in AbsoluteLayout, if you want to set ListView as center in AbsoluteLayout, you can use  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds and AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags to set ListView position.

Please take a look the following code:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackLayout
            HeightRequest="150"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image
                x:Name="logo"
                Aspect="AspectFit"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Source="a11.jpg" />
        </StackLayout>
        <AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="Center">

            <Label
                x:Name="l_trinkeinladung"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0.5,-1,-1"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                FontSize="Title"
                Text="Lorem ipsum test text, this is test aaaaaaaaaaaaa"
                TextColor="Black"
                WidthRequest="300" />
            <ListView
                x:Name="listview1"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5,.5,200,270"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                BackgroundColor="Red"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                ItemsSource="{Binding players}"
                RowHeight="50">

                <!--<ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            /*Stack for properites*/
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>-->

            </ListView>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </StackLayout>
```

The Screenshot like this:

[image]

**AbsoluteLayoutFlags** specifies how values will be interpreted and has the 
following predefined options:

**None** – interprets all values as absolute. This is the default value if no layout flags are specified.

**All** – interprets all values as proportional.

**WidthProportional** – interprets the Width value as proportional and all other values as absolute.

**HeightProportional** – interprets only the height value as proportional with all other values absolute.

**XProportional** – interprets the X value as proportional, while treating all other values as absolute.

**YProportional** – interprets the Y value as proportional, while treating all other values as absolute.

**PositionProportional** – interprets the X and Y values as proportional, while the size values are interpreted as absolute.

**SizeProportional** – interprets the Width and Height values as proportional while the position values are absolute.

About using Xamarin.Forms AbsoluteLayout, please take a look the detailed info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolute-layout